# Paste together columns but ignore NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I want to paste together multiple columns but ignore NAs.

Here's a basic working example of what the df looks like and what I'd like it to look like. Does anyone have any tips?

```
df <- data.frame("col1" = c("A", NA, "B", "C"),
                 "col2" = c(NA, NA, NA, "E"),
                 "col3" = c(NA, "D", NA, NA),
                 "col4" = c(NA, NA, NA, NA))

df_fixed <- data.frame("col" = c("A", "D", "B", "C,E"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `paste`.

```
data.frame(col1=sapply(apply(df, 1, \(x) x[!is.na(x)]), paste, collapse=','))
#   col1
# 1    A
# 2    D
# 3    B
# 4  C,E
```

Or without `apply`:

```
data.frame(col1=unname(as.list(as.data.frame(t(df))) |>
             (\(x) sapply(x, \(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=',')))()))
#   col1
# 1    A
# 2    D
# 3    B
# 4  C,E
```

To add as a column use `transform`.

```
transform(df, colX=sapply(apply(df, 1, \(x) x[!is.na(x)]), paste, collapse=','))
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 colX
# 1    A <NA> <NA>   NA    A
# 2 <NA> <NA>    D   NA    D
# 3    B <NA> <NA>   NA    B
# 4    C    E <NA>   NA  C,E
```

**Note:** Actually, you also could replace `\(x) x[!is.na(x)]` by `na.omit`, since it's attributes vanish; see e.g. *@ G. Grothendieck*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70368143/6574038).

Comment: Thanks for this! And if I want to save this as a new column in a df, what's the syntax like? The following returns df$col1.col1

df$col1 <- data.frame(col1=sapply(apply(df[1:4], 1, \(x) x[!is.na(x)]), paste, collapse=','))

Comment: @user9974638 Using `transform`, see update.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

We may use `unite` which can have `na.rm` as argument

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   unite(col, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep=",")
```

-output

```
  col
1   A
2   D
3   B
4 C,E
```

---

Or using `base R` with `do.call` and `trimws`

```
data.frame(col = trimws(do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ",")),
      whitespace = "(?:,?NA,?)+"))
```

-output

```
  col
1   A
2   D
3   B
4 C,E
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible base R solution:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(col=apply(df,1, function(x) paste0(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")))

df2

#>   col
#> 1   A
#> 2   D
#> 3   B
#> 4 C,E
```

Answer (score 1):

Use na.omit and toString.  No packages are used.

```
data.frame(col = apply(df, 1, function(x) toString(na.omit(x)))
##    col
## 1    A
## 2    D
## 3    B
## 4 C, E
```

Use one of  these instead of the anonymous function shown if spaces in the output are a problem:

```
function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",") 
function(x) gsub(", ", ",", toString(na.omit(x)))
```

Comment: Had this in mind, but there's a space after the comma which differs from expected result.

Comment: It isn't clear that that is really material however I added some alternatives just in case.